# Integrating ember.js with tornado templates

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to move an application from using tornado templates (to be more accurate, it's jinja with an adapter) to ember.js.
It is my understanding that ember.js has very strong opinions on how to compose the final rendered product. In practice, it seems that the whole application must be generated from ember templates on the client side. The server side just provides data in REST format.

Is it possible to have ember work and take control only on some parts of a page that is mostly rendered by tornado templates (a la jquery plugins), or do I have to completely switch to ember?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome, glad you're looking hard at Ember! You're right, Ember has definite opinions on how things should work :-) Despite that, it is indeed doable to migrate over in chunks.

You have a few options on how to handle this.

#### 1. Build out from a single div on a page

You can see this in action on the [builds](https://emberjs.com) page on the main Ember site (which is a small Ember app). Source for it is available here: https://github.com/ember-learn/builds/

Of interest is the fact that you can define the `rootElement` that you want Ember to render in to (see https://github.com/ember-learn/builds/blob/master/app/app.js although we should actually move that line to the config file). Once you have Ember on the page it is then possible to have it both interact with external Javascript or to have external Javascript call in as needed.

#### 2. Sprinkle Ember components on to a page

If you need Ember to control multiple parts of the same page, you may want to look at https://github.com/mitchlloyd/ember-islands That addon is designed to work with server-rendered pages, so may not fit your setup. But it's another example of how to refactor in.

#### 3. Use the new GlimmerJS (alpha)

You could also start refactoring into Ember using the newly announced [GlimmerJS](https://glimmerjs.com/). The goal for this library is to allow folks to sprinkle in Ember and then as they need page routing and other aspects of Ember, allow them to switch over. So it may fit what you are after.

Note however that the GlimmerJS layer (on top of the Glimmer vm) is still quite new. What is there works well, but much of the Ember polish is still being added. So shipping to production could take some work ...

Comment: Thanks. I think we will go with the first option. We are basically rewriting everything so that the rendering is client side. So you confirm that basically the philosophy is pretty much this: the server gives you only the basic html (header, css linking, etc, and an empty body). All the rendering and template application is done client side, and the server is only returning REST+JSON data.